# Primefaces function clearFilters() doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code:

```
<p:tree value="#{sessBean.root}" var="node" animate="true" id="idTree" selectionMode="single" selection="#{sessBean.selectedNode}" >
        <p:ajax listener="#{reqBean.doBtnSearch}" event="select" onstart="PF('tblDataWidget').clearFilters();" update=":form1:tabView:tblData" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.descr}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <p:commandButton value="Add" icon="ui-icon-plus" id="doBtnAdd" action="#{reqBean.doBtnAddEntry}" update="tblData" oncomplete="PF('tblDataWidget').clearFilters();" />
```

I have a dataTable (tblData) with many entries, which are loaded and displayed when a tree node is clicked. So far, no problems. Datatable has filters on some columns, which also works fine. The problem appears, when I want to clear the filter (on button and tree node click). When I click the 'Add' button (see the code above), the filters are cleared as expected, but when I click on a tree node, clearing the filters doesn't work. Both commandButton and tree component are contained in a tabView container.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your suggestions!

PS: using PrimeFaces 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
<p:ajax listener="#{reqBean.doBtnSearch}" event="select" onstart="PF('tblDataWidget').clearFilters();" update="#{p:component('tblData')},#{p:component('idTree')}" />
```